where can i get all the depth levels of orderbook data for BTC?
Right now, I was able to get an orderbook snapshots data for BTCUSDT in Binance. The problem with this data is that each depth level of the orderbook increases every 5 cents or so. For total of 20 depth levels, it amounts to only 1 dollar higher or lower from the mid price.
Because i intend to hold the position for longer (around a few hours to a couple days), I want to see the bigger picture, i.e. in Binance website, you can select, for example, "10" dollars for the orderbook and the orderbook depth levels are in increments of 10 dollars. I want this type of data, and not the orderbook data where the depth levels increase in increments of 5 cents. Is there a way to obtain such data?

This answer does not give you orderbook depth levels with 10 dollar increments directly, but does give you a broader range of depth:
So to have more levels than 20, you could simply use api provided by binance:
https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=1000
and you can get levels up to 1000.
You may also want to manage a local orderbook based on this, see How to manage a local order book correctly from binance, and they provide a official python script here:
https://github.com/binance/binance-toolbox-python/blob/master/manage_local_order_book.py
With the above setting you could then do your own calculations for any arbitrary price increment.

oh i forgot to add however that i was also looking for historical data as well. I was able to find the API for the current orderbook data, but it's very hard to find the historical one with high limit depth levels

@KevinKim I think Binance also offers historical orderbook deltas (TDepth) and you could recover the book in the same way. Check https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/binance-futures-order-book-historical-data-e707685b4e0f408fa7c1b9ccd8ea7aa9. However, it is available only to vip users now and you need to have a whitelisted api.

Usually one has to pay for data with this resolution, as there are no free resources available. You could check Tardis.dev, which provides free sample data for the 1st day each month, or you'll have to log the data yourself.
